# Has anyone been able to get bullet to work in Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, google-colaboratory

I am testing out 'bullet' in Colab.  I installed bullet and it seems to be present to import. I get `'error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')'`.  It does ask me to chose a fruit before it breaks.
I would try it somewhere else but I'm at work and am unable to do so.  This is an example from the bullet repo.

```py
from bullet import Bullet
cli = Bullet(prompt = "n\ Please choose a fruit: ",
            choices = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'strawberry'],
            indent = 0,
            align = 5,
            margin = 2,
            shift = 0,
            bullet = "",
            pad_right = 5
        )

result = cli.launch()
print("You chose: ", result)
```

Comment: I think bullet uses unix style tty controls and I don't think these methods work inside a Jupyter notebook because it is a web app and not really a standard unix console.  You might want to try using widgets (some of which work in colab) instead.  https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html

Comment: Okay, thanks for that Aaron.  I'll check it out.  I just went with bullet because I've heard it mentioned several times and how much people liked it.

Answer (score 0):

I may not know the answer to whether or not 'bullet' will work in Colab, but I do know it worked in PythonAnywhere - at least as far as I've gone with it.